# HTML email going to spam

Tags: email, html-email, email-attachments

Not sure if this is in the right place, but it's all stemming from a PHP email send script that isn't working.

I have an email server for my clients that exists at email.thoughtspacedesigns.com. I run multiple domains from this server (e.g. pittsburghphotography.co). I've set up SPF and DKIM for these external domains, and plain text messages are going through just fine, but anything that contains an HTML attachment (even if it's accompanied by plain text) is going directly to spam when sent to any gmail account. So for example, if I send an HTML email from contact@pittsburghphotography.co, regardless of the client I use (Mac Mail, WordPress, pure PHP script), it goes into spam. I'm not sure what I can do to circumvent this issue as I've already set up just about all of the verification factors I thought were possible. Any insight?

Comment: This email you're sending wouldn't happen to be spam, would it?

Answer (score 1):

Emails can get sent to the spam folder for a variety of reasons.  Here are some things you might look into:

Every email server has a numbered rating and that can effect how your email is delivered.  Check that at [senderscore.org](https://www.senderscore.org).

Another thing you might look into is if your email server is on any "Black lists" meaning that you tanked your senders score and got put on a list as a know spammer.  Don't feel bad if you are, it's easy to wind up on one.  Check for that at [blacklistmonitoring.com](http://www.blacklistmonitoring.com/).

Also, a simple way to check for spam keywords is [isnotspam.com](http://isnotspam.com/).  There are other spam checkers out there but that's the one I like.

EDIT: I also forgot to mention gmail can be a bit more fickle than other email clients when it comes to spam.  It's just something in their spam filtering algorithm that is more sensitive than other applications.

Best of luck!